# Generate "file://" URIs in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, uri

I am searching for a way to obtain a proper file:/ URI from inside Windows Explorer.  Basically I would like to have a context menu entry which says "copy file URI to clipboard".  Does something like that exist?

This is not a duplicate of "Copy filename to clipboard" since I want a file URI and not the path name.

To clarify: I am looking to get "file:///c:/Temp/foo%20bar.txt" and neither "C:\Temp\foo bar.txt" nor "foo bar.txt" nor "C:\Temp".

Comment: Thanks!  One of the responses mentions [FileMenu Tools](http://www.lopesoft.com/en/fmtools/info.html) which has that functionality but it retains spaces in the copied string which makes it an invalid URI. :-(

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "Copy filename to clipboard" since I want a file URI and not the path name.

Comment: To clarify: I am looking to get "file:///c:/Temp/foo%20bar.txt" and neither "C:\Temp\foo bar.txt" nor "foo bar.txt" nor "C:\Temp".

Answer (score 3):

Just came up with this VBS.

```
If WScript.arguments.count > 0 Then
    Dim WshShell: Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    strPath = "file:///" & Wscript.Arguments(0)
    strPath = Replace(strPath,"\","/")
    strPath = Replace(strPath," ","%20")
    sCmd = "%comspec% /c<nul (set/p anyvariable=" & Chr(34) & strPath & Chr(34) & ")|clip.exe"
    WshShell.Run sCmd,0,0
    Set WshShell = Nothing
End If
```

Save it as a .VBS file. Drag and drop a file on to the VBScript and it copies the file's URI to clipboard. You can implement it in the right-click menu if required.

It copies the file name to memory, reverses the slashes, replaces spaces with "%20", and appends "file:///" at the beginning. It's a basic script which supports only one file name / argument. You can modify it as required.

**Add the Script to your Send To folder**

You may place a shortcut of the script in your Send To folder. Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `shell:sendto` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Create a shortcut to the script in the Send To folder and name it accordingly. (eg. `Copy File URI`)

Now, right-click a file, click Send To and click `Copy File URI`. The file path would be copied to the clipboard, in the URI format as below.

```
file:///C:/Users/jack/desktop/list-of-items.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The VBS script is nice, but there is no way it handles all the edge cases handled by the likes of [UrlCreateFromPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-urlcreatefrompatha) or .NET's [System.URI](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/UriExt.cs,fb5ba9a46b2384ae,references).

Fortunately, both are easy to use, here's what I did:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AbsoluteUriGenerator
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 1)
            {
                var executableName = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Name + ".exe";
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: {0} pathToConvert", executableName);
                Console.WriteLine("Example: {0} \"C:\\foo\"", executableName);
                return 1;
            }

            var path = args[0];
            Console.WriteLine("Resolving file:// URI of path: {0}", path);
            var fileUri = new Uri(path).AbsoluteUri;

            Console.WriteLine("Setting clipboard to resolved file:// URI: {0}", fileUri);
            Clipboard.SetText(fileUri);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You can copy it to your `shell:sendto` folder, here's a compiled version: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj2cMNVj29ben4B_mh9Md5R4ghBlMQ